# Cannot Mount Window Share Folder On Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-4, mount, samba

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=[Username],password=[Password],uid=1000,gid=1000 //192.168.100.90/TempFolder/MyFiles /mnt/NetworkBackup

    error(112): Host is down


sudo smbclient -N -L //192.168.100.90/
do_connect: Connection to 192.168.100.90 failed (Error NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT)
```

Could anyone suggest to me how to solve this error? Pls let me know if I need to update the question.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your windows computer. Or maybe a general problem with the network connectivity. Doesn't seem to be Pi specific.

Comment: general linux questions do not belong here ... same for windows questions

Comment: The error message you posted says, `Host is down`.  At the risk of insulting your intelligence, I'll ask why you didn't bother to mention what you did to eliminate one apparently obvious issue; i.e. is your host up???

Comment: @Seamus Yes Seamus, the host is up. That's why.

Comment: OK - `mount` can be picky, so let's try a few steps to troubleshoot. Run `apt-cache policy cifs-utils` to verify you have cifs-utils installed & get the version. If you do, try using `smbfs` instead of `cifs`.

Answer (score 0):

"Host is down" error is caused by a combination of two things: A SMB protocol version mismatch, and the CIFS client on Linux returning a misleading error message. In order to fix this a version entry needs to be added to the mount command. By default Raspberry Pi OS will only use versions 2.1 and above, which are compatible with Windows 7 and later. Older devices, including some NAS, may require version 1.0:

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is just that port 445(SMB port) is not open earlier, so that I cannot mount. Make sure this port is open before mounting winshare folder on Pi.